# I receive "Object LIbrary feature not Supported" on Evernote SDK VBA sample at ListNotebooksForCOM()

Tags: excel, vba, windows, sdk, evernote

I installed the Windows SDK, opened the sample spreadsheet and checked the reference to "Evernote Cloud SDK for Windows".  I get the error when I run the VBA macro

This is the sample code:

```
Sub EvernoteSDKSample()

    Dim EvernoteSession As New ENSessionForCOM

    ' Be sure to put your own consumer key and consumer secret here.
    Call EvernoteSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("hhagell", "3da657d6f5855f7b")

    If EvernoteSession.sharedSession.IsAuthenticated = False Then
        Call EvernoteSession.sharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote
    End If

    ' Get a list of all notebooks in the user's account.
    Dim myNotebooks As ENCollection
    Set myNotebooks = EvernoteSession.sharedSession.ListNotebooksForCOM()
```

I found a couple of people had the same error and did not find a resolution (at least one not documented)

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers

Any thoughts would be appreciated.